# Android push notification icon - how to change background color

Tags: android, angular, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor

I'm using Angular and Capacitor in my web/mobile app. Users can receive push messages send by Firebase. How can I change the background color of notification icon? I have tried all options without result, I think. My icon is transparent png.

In AndroidManifest.xml I already have config:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_action_name"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:resource="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

Color what I want to change:

[image]